# a basic question about variable in Mathematica

Tags: variable

I can't describe exactly the problem I'm experiencing, but this kind of problem has a remarkable feature, that is, commands which couldn't work in the before can be executed correctly when i turn off the Mathematica and reopen it. Later, I know function "Clear[]", it can also solve this kind problem in the most occasions. But sometimes it's not very convenient to use Clear[] for multiple variables. I think this kind problem probably has something to do with the naming of variables and the life cycle and scope, and I want to ask 1. if there are some good habits to avoid such problems, and 2. whether there is a way to solve it other than restart Mathematica.

Comment: `Clear["Global\`*"]` will clear all symbols in the `Global` context

Comment: If I'm in that sort of experimental phase where I keep changing my function definitions, I'll sometimes end up _adding_ DownValues when I intended to _replace_ DownValues. If I realize that I may be in this cycle for awhile, I'll just put a `ClearAll` in front of my definitions. So, if I'm defining `myFunc[...]:=...`, I'll change it to `ClearAll[myFunc];myFunc[...]:=...`. Then, each time I make a change and re-evaluate that cell, I know I'm starting from a "clean slate". Typically I'll remove these superfluous `ClearAll`s when things have settled.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from. In this particular case, you can include a minimal example (using Mathematica code, not an image) to get more focused replies. Thanks.

Comment: Another important thing is, one should always keep an eye on the color of the variable. If a variable is _empty_, it's blue, otherwise it's black.